# mobile browser - how to remove drag to horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, mobile, browser, touch

In a page with width larger than the mobile viewport width. I can swipe left or right to scroll horizontally. How to remove that? Because I will do a horizontal scroll with javascript manually.

Comment: How will you be doing it with JavaScript? Our answer could break your JS scrollbars

Comment: It doesn't seem like a good idea to disable native browser functionality to re-implement it using script. Javascript is inherently unreliable and usually is inferior for UI effects and functionality when compared to built–in features.

Comment: I trying to remove horizontal scroll to implement my own scripts and keep the built-in vertical scroll. window.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
 }, false);  this will stop both scroll. How to keep the vertical scroll?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS [overflow-x](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow-x) property:

```css
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```